# Proof of A & B from ¬(A → ¬B) using rules of inference

Tags: logic, propositional-logic

I have been tasked with proving A & B from −(A → −B). However, I'm only allowed to use the following rules:

ModusPonens,
ModusTollens,
ConditionalProof,
DoubleNegation,
AndIntroduction,
AndElimination,
OrIntroduction,
OrElimination,
ReductioAdAbsurdium

I'm able to construct a proof using De Morgan's laws however, I'm struggling to create a proof using ONLY these deductions. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Assume  ¬A y, derive a contradiction and by DN derive A. Then Assume ¬B, derive a contradiction and by DN derive B. Then conclude with AndIntro.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a homework forum for logic classes